# How to archive Xcode project of Cocoa bundle?

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, bundle, appkit

I started working on the cocoa app that can be extended by custom plug-ins (loadable bundles). And I'm able to load a plug-in in the app (bundle created in my app project). I started wondering, how a 3rd party can create a plug-in and what's the experience – to build the plug-in knowing only app's interface. I created a new Xcode (v12.5) bundle project, added shared framework that exposes the app's API, wrote my custom code, everything compiles and works.
But when I archive it, I can't do anything with it – the archive is empty (there are dsyms only) and there is no "product".
The type of the archive is the "Generic Xcode Archive".
I'd expect to see my custom bundle with the binary, "Resources" folder etc. so I can share or upload it for the notarizing service…
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally solved it – you have to set the `Skip Install` to false in the Build Settings -> Deployment.